# PHP: print all days between a given day and end of month

Tags: php, arrays, date

I **don't** want to return DATE (Y-m-d).

I need to print all days until end of month from a given day **independently of the month or year**.

I tried both [$array as $i] - [$array as $key] and didn't work.

$myday (for example = 19)
return $days

would result:
Array
[0] => 20
[1] => 21
[2] => 22
[3] => 23
...
[31] => 31 || [30] => 30 || [28] => 28

I would need each value for $days to compare each to another field.

Didn't try to use $myday as regular number instead of treating as date. And not use strtotime, mktime....

**EDITING**

Need something very simple like this one:

```
$output = array();
for ($i=$myday+1;$i<=31 || $i<=30 || $i<=28;$i++) {
$output[] = $i;
}
```

But print_r won't do it, I need to return as each value to use in different if conditions

Comment: you need to know what month it is to find out how many days are in that month, so its not independent of the month, its also not independent on the year (leap years). you need to post some code or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done using [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php), and [relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

```
$start    = (new DateTime())->setDate(date('Y'), date('m'), $myday + 1);
$end      = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$days     = array();
foreach($period as $date) {
    $days[] = $date->format('d');
}
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 24
    [5] => 25
    [6] => 26
    [7] => 27
    [8] => 28
    [9] => 29
    [10] => 30
    [11] => 31
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/185603)

Comment: Thanks John but I was trying to avoid the use of year and month - I was trying to use the most simplified version to get the range between 2 numbers and returning each of them as value. Return the results as value so I can use each value in different if condition.

Comment: If you don't specify a year and month how do you determine what month it is? And thus the number of days in the month?

Comment: An if(){} before it is checking the month and its days - no need for it. I just need to explode the remaining days of the month to get each  to compare to something else.